# __init__ method in PySide

Tags: python

In a few tutorials I've read that for `__init__` method I have to do something like this:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
    ...
```

However, in PySide I found this. What does the line `QWidget.__init__(self)` do and do I need it?

```
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `cls.__init__(self)` (where `cls` can be any class), will simply call the `cls`'s `__init__` on `self`. Here's an example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = True
        print('Initializing object {} on Foo.__init__!'.format(self))

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__init__(self)
        self.bar = True
        print('Initializing object {} on Bar.__init__!'.format(self))
```

Now creating an instance of `Bar` will output both `__init__`s:

```
>>> b = Bar()
Initializing object <__main__.Bar object at 0x00000000039329E8> on Foo.__init__!
Initializing object <__main__.Bar object at 0x00000000039329E8> on Bar.__init__!
```

Also, `b` now has both attributes, `foo` and `bar`.

---

You should **rarely** be calling other class's `__init__`, unless you're subclassing that other class. The example above is usually incorrect, since `Bar` is not subclassing `Foo`.

Even when you're subclassing a class, you shouldn't be accessing that class directly using its name, but instead use the Python's built-in function `super()`:

```
# "WRONG"  (usually)
class X(Y):
    def __init__(self):
        Y.__init__(self)

# RIGHT
class X(Y):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # self is omitted when using super()
```

Comment: In this case in Python3 when using 'super().__init__()' the parent object for 'Bar' class has to be 'Foo'. When using 'Foo.__init__(self)' the parent can be 'object' class. 

So, basically, we use super to run '__init__'in parent and to inherit and access methods and attributes of that parent :)

Not calling '__init__' on superclass is vorbiden if I understand it correctly

PS: How to get that grey 'code' in comments?

Comment: Yes, when using `super()` you must be subclassing the other class. You can use `super()` in Python 2 too: `super(Foo, self).__init__()`

Comment: However, in Python 2 when using "super(Foo, self).__init__()" with parent "Foo" in class "Bar" it only prints "__init__" from "Bar" class.

Initializing object <__main__.Bar object at 0x7f2cfca51310> on Bar.__init__

Comment: When you say _self is omitted when using super()_ is `self` a child object? This is very confusing, sometimes it needs `self` and sometimes not

Comment: @Hrvoje I mean that you don't have to explicitly pass in the `self` argument, it gets passed in automatically when using `super()`. Compare: `Foo.__init__(self, x)` and `super().__init__(x)`. So by self getting omitted, I only meant that it gets passes in automatically whenever you use `super()`. If you don't use `super()`, then you have to pass in `self`

Comment: Thanks Markus, this is clear now. What is this `x` used for? I often see `def __init__(self, parent=None)` and then `super().init_(parent)`

Answer (score 1):

This line invokes `__init__` method of base class.

```
class App(QWidget)
```

`App` class inherits from `QWidget` class. Therefore, you must invoke initialize of base class when you inits instance of `App` class. In *Python 3* you can do same thing (invoke base `__init__`) with

```
super().__init__()
```

In this case

```
class App
```

`App` class hasn't a base class.